# How to include popups from above in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup, custom-controls

I want to add calendar as a popup as shown in attached images. I have tried nesting grid with stack layout as well as stack layout but of no use. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my Xaml Code

```
 <ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid BackgroundColor="Blue">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainStackLayout" Grid.Row="0" >

        </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">

        <Grid Padding="0" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label x:Name="PageHeading" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='75,60,0,0', Android='75,30,20,0'}" Text="I DAG" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PageHeading}" 
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}" />
            <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage Margin="{OnPlatform iOS='0,60,0,0', Android='0,30,20,0'}" 
                    Source="Calender.svg" 
                    WidthRequest="20" 
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                >
                <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding ShowDialogCommand}"  NumberOfTapsRequired="1"> </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
            </ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage>

        </Grid>

                    <StackLayout  Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" >

                        <Frame                               
                            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"                                
                            Padding="10,20,0,10" 
                            HasShadow="False"
                            IsClippedToBounds="True" BackgroundColor="#ffffff" CornerRadius="15" >


                                <views:CleaningListDataTemplate></views:CleaningListDataTemplate>


                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>


    </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I have added calendar to `mainStackLayout` in code behind as

```
calendarView = new CalendarView(new CalendarGlobalData()
            {
                MinDateRange = DateTime.Now,
                MaxDateRange = DateTime.Now,
                Parent = this
            });

            mainStackLayout.Children.Add(calendarView);
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is wrong with what you have tried?

Comment: i want to display pop up from top of the page. Bt my calendar gets added to middle of page.. :(

Comment: Have you tried add/remove calendar to the mainStackLayout when you want to show/hide it？

Comment: i m adding calendar in code behind and then it occupies whole page. Any help?? @MSFT

Comment: Try to give the calendar a fixed heightRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Rg Popup for Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) which is easier and a handy way to show popup in Xamarin. It is free to use as well.

Install the plugin in all the projects. [Here you can find the NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/).

- Add the PopUp in your Xaml
- There are built-in methods they provide to Show/Hide the PopUp.

```
     Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true)
     Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true)
```

> Refer to their [documentation](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki) for more details.

There is also a demo to refer to, in case, if you are new to Xamarin. Check it: 
https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/tree/develop/Samples

Comment: i want a popup to appear from top of the image. Is this possible using this plugin..??

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can position it wherever you want. The popup has some built-in animations to have a pleasant experience as well.

Comment: I have tried using the plugin. It works well. Bt it navigates to another page. what i need is when user clicks calendar button it displays the calendar as popup and list view is slightly pushed down with animation. when user touches anywhere else other than popup or selects date. Calendar moves up and list view moves to its original position. Can you guide me if thats possible in any way.

Comment: All you have to do to show a popup is to use the below code. 
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);

If you want to push down the list view, then you have to translate it in the code. Or simply you can place a blank view at the top of your ListView and animate its positioning in the code when you click the calendar button. You can shrink it back when the popup closes.